# Reason behind the title "Logan"

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, title, logan

The past standalone movies regarding Wolverine were named with titles containing the word "wolverine" but the recent movie is just named **Logan**.

Is there any particular reason behind keeping this name as the movie title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons.

Firstly, the movie is loosely based on the *Old Man Logan* comic books series.

> The basic concept of Old Man Logan—that of an aged Wolverine on a "buddy road trip" across America — was the inspiration for the 2017 Wolverine film Logan.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_Logan#Original_Story)</sup>

---

More importantly, perhaps, the movie is **about the man, Logan,** rather than the superhero, Wolverine, and how his era (and life) are coming to an end.

Additionally, it's implied that there will, perhaps, be a *new* Wolverine in future movies (as there is now in the comics where Logan is just *Logan*).

> After the *Death of Wolverine* [comic run], X-23 took the mantle of Wolverine, but Old Man Logan was brought in to serve as an X-Man and featured in his own ongoing series.

Comment: I read to today that future films like the remaining two New Mutant films in it's horror trliogy, James Mangold's X-23 film, and Gambit may all be in Limbo now thanks to Disney's takeover.  It's unlcear what will happen with Deadpool, but Bob Iger made a statement that there may be room for "rated-R" brand at Disney (but we'll see).